# ASP .Net Core 2.0 - Lectura appsettings.json desde una clase sin parametrizar

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, patrones-de-diseño, diseño-de-clases

estoy empezando con una web asp.net core 2.0 mvc y no consigo leer directamente desde una clase el valor del appsettings.json (ConnectionString) que necesito.

Buscando he encontrado bastante documentación, aunque ninguna consigue lo que yo quiero. Resumiendo toda la documentación que he leido, lo que propone la mayoría es lo siguiente:

1. Crear una clase "appSettings"
2. Añadir un nuevo servicio en Setup.cs (ConfigureServices)
3. Inyectar los valores al constructor del controlador y acceder desde ahí a los datos.

Uno de los tantos ejemplos que he encontrado:https://benjii.me/2016/04/new-configuration-appsettings-mvc6-web-config-gone/

El problema que tengo es que estoy estructurando el código en tres capas (interfaz, lógica de negocio y acceso a datos) que se llaman la una a la otra respectivamente y no veo la manera de hacer llegar hasta la capa de acceso a datos la cadena de conexión sin tener que enviarla por parámetro a través de las distintas capas.

Ahora mismo la idea que tengo en la cabeza es la de poder leer desde la clase de acceso a datos los valores del appsettings.json, aunque si alquien conoce otra manera mejor de hacerlo también me gustaría saberlo.

Gracias por adelantado.

**Edit1:**

**AppSettings.cs**

Clase que he creado para almacenar los datos de appsettings.json

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public Connection Connection { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

Entiendo que aquí se agrega al contenedor de servicios la clase "AppSettings".

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddOptions();

    // Add appSettings
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(settings =>
    {
        settings.Connection = new Connection()
        {
            ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]
        };
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

**DataAccess.cs**

Capa de acceso a datos. Donde debo de poder acceder a AppSettings.

```
private readonly AppSettings _settings;

public DataAccess(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
{
    _settings = settings.Value;
}
```

**BusinessLogic.cs**

Capa de negocio, donde instancio la capa de acceso a datos. Me genera un error de compilación porque faltan parámetros que enviar al constructor, lo cual me parece lógico. Quizás no consigo entender muy bien la inyección de dependencias.

```
public Business()
{
    Data = new DataAccess();
}
```

**Edit2: Así es como lo he solucionado, por si a alguien le sirve para algo**

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services
        services.AddMvc();

        // Configure AppSettings
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(settings =>
        {
            settings.Data = new Data()
            {
                ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"].ToString()
            };
        });

        // Configure BusinessLogic
        services.AddSingleton<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic>();
        // Configure DataAccess
        services.AddSingleton<IDataAccess, DataAccess>();
    }

     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) ...
}
```

**DataAccess.cs**

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private readonly AppSettings _settings;

    public DataAccess(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return _settings.Data.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

> En la capa de acceso a datos creo un método de prueba que devuelve la
>   cadena de conexión.

**BusinessLogic.cs**

```
public class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
{
    private readonly IDataAccess _data;

    public BusinessLogic(IDataAccess data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return _data.GetConnectionString();
    }
}
```

> En la capa de negocio creo otro método de prueba que devuelve la
>   cadena de conexión. Este a su vez la obtiene de la capa de datos.

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBusinessLogic _businness;

    public HomeController(IBusinessLogic business)
    {
        _businness = business;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new HomeModel(_businness.GetConnectionString()));
    }
}
```

> En el controlador de la vista Home, pinto por pantalla la cadena de
>   conexión obtenida de la capa de negocio.

Comment: DataAccess y Business deberian implementa una interfaz que luego defines en la inyeccion de asp.net core. alli solo veo el constructor pero no la definicion de la clase

Comment: no puedes usar el new de DataAccess en Business, tienes que inyectar todo con interfaces

Comment: edite la respuesta para completar el ejemplo basado en tu implementacion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si defines la clase appSettings en un proyecto separado que puedas referenciar desde la capa de acceso a datos y la web, entonces podrias inyectar el ´IOptions<>´ en el constructor de la clase

[Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

Esta claro que la clase de acceso a datos debe resolver por inyeccion de dependencia, para que el IOptions aplique

```
public class xxDataAccess : IxxDataAccess {

    private readonly AppSettings settings;

    public xxDataAccess(IOptions<AppSettings> settings){

        this.settings = settings.Value;

    }

    //resto codigo

}
```

Basado en tu ejemplo seria

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess {

   private readonly AppSettings _settings;

   public DataAccess(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
   {
       _settings = settings.Value;
   }
}


public class Business: IBusiness {

   private readonly IDataAccess data;

   public Business(IDataAccess data)
   {
       this.data = data;
   }
}
```

recuerda definir el Business en el constructor del controller y todo esto en la inyeccion del config de asp.net core

Comment: Hola Leandro. Primero que nada, gracias por tu tiempo. He intentado hacerlo como me comentas pero no lo consigo. He editado la pregunta con las modificaciones que he añadido. Si pudieras mirarlo te lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Mi consejo es que si estas empezando con ASP.Net Core por que no crear tu Web por defecto en MVC que viene bien implementado y no tendrías que gastar tanto tiempo en las capas y la inyección de dependencias. Para qué reinventar la rueda?

Comment: Hola Vicente. Agradezco tu consejo, pero estoy levantando esta web precisamente para intentar familiarizarme con ciertos conceptos de .Net Core. Es un proyecto personal por "trastear y aprender" y me gustaría seguir en esta línea hasta ver a donde me lleva :)

Comment: Creo que ya lo he pillado. He hecho unas pruebas y parece que funciona. Edité la pregunta original añadiendo cómo ha quedado, por si a alguien le pudiera servir de algo. A demás, si tienes alguna sugerencia o comentario de algo que se pueda mejorar o corregir me encantaría saberlo. Muchas gracias por todo.

Answer (score 2):

En Startup cuando configuras tu conexión puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("nombre_de_conexion");
```

Como mencionas Business Layer puedo creer que usas algún DBContext para el acceso a la base de datos, de ser así, en Startup se encuentra el siguiente método:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //aquí puedes poner algo como esto:
    services.AddDbContext<TuDBContext>(options =>      
    options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("nombre_de_conexion")));
}
```

PD: options.UseSqlServer puede cambiar según lo que utilices para base de datos, puede ser UseSqlite o UseMysql.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener la cadena de conexión desde cualquier lugar del proyecto, reconstruyendo IConfiguration a partir del archivo "appsetting.json" conociendo la ubicación con "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" si esta en el mismo proyecto o asignando la ruta donde se encuentra el appsetting.json.

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

private string GetConnectionString()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    return Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

}
```

Recuerda tener en el archivo appsetting.json la siguiente estructura:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=((local));Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;user id=xx;password=xxxx;"
  }
}
```